# Vim: Show current json path

Tags: json, api, vim

I'm editing a very large, nested JSON doc (rightscale api incase you're interested) in vim and would love to know the current json-path (like xpath for json) Something like:

Given the JSON:

```
 {                                    
     "leve1": {                       
         "level2": {                  
             "level3": {              
                 "name": "goes here"  
             }                        
         }                            
     }                                
}
```

With my cursor between "name": and "goes here" i'd like a command (or status line) that shows me:

```
level1/level2/level3/name
```

or similar.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 7):

I recently wrote a plugin for this called [vim-jsonpath](https://github.com/mogelbrod/vim-jsonpath). It currently provides the following commands (that of course can be mapped):

- `:JsonPath`: Echoes the path to the identifier under the cursor.
- `:JsonPath path.to.prop`: Searches the active buffer for the given path, placing the cursor on it if found.

Answer (score 3):

I've written two mappings that use the *fold information* (so they should work with *any* structure, not just JSON). For your example, they output

```
{ / "leve1": { / "level2": { / "level3": {
```

and (long version):

```
1  {
2      "leve1": {
3          "level2": {
4              "level3": {
```

Here is the scriptlet. It depends on my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433).

```
" [count]z?     Print all lines (with numbers) that start a fold where
"           the current line is contained in (for [count] upper
"           levels). When a line consists of just a symbol like "{",
"           the preceding non-empty line is printed, too.
" [count]z/     Like z?, but use a short output format with all line
"           contents concatenated, and without line numbers and
"           symbols.
if ! exists('g:PrintFoldHierarchySymbolLinePattern')
    let g:PrintFoldHierarchySymbolLinePattern = '^\s*{\s*$'
endif
function! s:PrintFoldHierarchy( count, isJoin )
    if foldclosed('.') != -1
        return 0
    endif

    let l:save_view = winsaveview()
        let l:levels = []
        let l:lnum = line('.')
        while (a:count ? len(l:levels) < a:count : 1)
            silent! normal! [z
            if line('.') == l:lnum
                break
            endif
            let l:lnum = line('.')
            call insert(l:levels, l:lnum)
            if getline(l:lnum) =~# g:PrintFoldHierarchySymbolLinePattern
                let l:precedingLnum = prevnonblank(l:lnum - 1)
                if l:precedingLnum > 0
                    if a:isJoin
                        let l:levels[0] = l:precedingLnum
                    else
                        call insert(l:levels, l:precedingLnum)
                    endif
                endif
            endif
        endwhile
    call winrestview(l:save_view)

    if a:isJoin
        echo
        let l:isFirst = 1
        for l:lnum in l:levels
            if l:isFirst
                let l:isFirst = 0
            else
                echohl SpecialKey
                echon ' / '
                echohl None
            endif
            echon ingo#str#Trim(getline(l:lnum))
        endfor
    else
        for l:lnum in l:levels
            echohl LineNr
            echo printf('%' . (ingo#window#dimensions#GetNumberWidth(1) - 1) . 'd ', l:lnum)
            echohl None
            echon getline(l:lnum)
        endfor
    endif

    return 1
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> z? :<C-u>if ! <SID>PrintFoldHierarchy(v:count, 0)<Bar>execute "normal! \<lt>C-\>\<lt>C-n>\<lt>Esc>"<Bar>endif<CR>
nnoremap <silent> z/ :<C-u>if ! <SID>PrintFoldHierarchy(v:count, 1)<Bar>execute "normal! \<lt>C-\>\<lt>C-n>\<lt>Esc>"<Bar>endif<CR>
```

You can put that into your `~/.vimrc` (or a separate `~/.vim/plugin/PrintFoldHierarchy.vim`), and invoke the mappings from normal mode via `z?` and `z/`.

Comment: No plugin for that script?

Comment: `z?` or `z/` in normal mode do nothing :(